# Can we make a text outline again into a text in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, inkscape, vector, typography

I am very new to Adobe Illustrator, I created a text outline by doing

```
1. Select the text
2. Goto Type -> Create Outlines (CTRL + SHIFT + O)
```

But what if I want to make those outlines again as a text? Please let me know.

For your reference below I am attaching the screenshot, please find the attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: No. Converting text to outlines is destructive. Text data and formatting such as font, point size, font weight, etc,  are removed when you convert to outlines.

Answer (score 4):

the short answer is no. you would need a script to read the shapes as OCR content and the convert it back into a string of text.  usually when such documents are made a duplicate layer containing editable text is kept in the file (you can also turn off that particular layer's capability to print as further security)

Comment: Welcome! +1 although even OCR isn't going to pick the right font 90% of the time. OCR will pick glyphs, but not typically match any font.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens that you want to include the edited letter outlines to text you have at least one easy possibility. You can paste them into text as inline graphics. That can happen at least in Adobe Indesign. Inline graphics for Illustrator has hanged in the feature wishlist.

Another more complex possibility is to create a new font in a font editor.

If the letter shapes have only slight or no distortion you can do as already said by others: use OCR to extract the text content (=characters, not its visible form). Adobe Acrobat Pro does it well. In addition there's available several advanced OCR programs, some also as freeware. Most of them expect to see good quality bitmap images of text (=rasterized vector images, photos or scanned text pages).